# Display Information through Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am new here and i want to ask a simple question to all of you as i am a beginner in PHP.
I have created a table in MySQL database with 4 columns named id , stuimg , stuname , studetail.
also i have created a page through which values and image gets stored into these columns. Now my problem is that how can i retrieve all these information stored in these columns and display it on a page (Including Image)

you can check my code and please correct if i am doing something wrong:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <table>
            <?php
                $p=$_GET['id'];       
                include('dbconfig.php');  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM aboutstudent where id ='$p'";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Image*:</td>
                        <td><input name="image" type="file" value="<?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];?>"  /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name*:</td>
                        <td><input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['name'];?>"  /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description*:</td>
                        <td><input name="des" type="textarea" value="<?php echo $data['description'];?>"  /> </td>
                    </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Be sure to use mysqli functions. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: your above code is working right ?

Comment: I have included the dbconfig.php into above code containing mysql connection.

Comment: <input name="image" type="file" value="<?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];?>"  /> ???

Comment: @CodingAnt No mate its not working, saying undefined index id

Comment: Do a `var_dump($data);` to see the structure of your code and you will see the indexes and data. $data['index'] is how to access the database's column information.

Comment: @CodingAnt You got my problem, I dont know how to retrieve image from database and display it.

Comment: $_FILES['image']['name'] in form for displaying from DB ?? look your php code is messed up

Comment: @srp003j <img src="<? php echo $['here what the field']; ?>" >

Comment: @CodingAnt yes its not correct ,totally messed up. can you help me out through this ? All i want is to display image that is stored in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you are directly passing variable to SQL query from $_GET, which is **HUGE** security issue! See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) or at least use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM aboutstudent where id ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($p) . "';";
```

Next, if your `dbconfig.php` contains correct credentilas AND connect you to database, your code looks fine, except `$_FILES['image']['name']`, which contains data only when input file is submited. And next, you can't set default value for `input type='file'`. If you have your image saved in database, use simple `$data['image'];`, otherwise provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to post to a new page without the id-variable being set.

Comment: can you help me out through this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="image" type="file" value="<?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];?>"  />

replace it 

<img src = "<?php $data['image']; ?>"> <!-- give full path where image is store  -->
```

and also remove  form while loop

it means write it out of while loop

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented your code, and this will work fine

```
<html>
 <body>
 <table>
<?php
  $p=$_GET['id'];       
  include('dbconfig.php');  
  $query = "SELECT * FROM aboutstudent where id ='$p'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
?>
        <tr>
         <td>Image*:</td>
         <td><img src="<?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];?>"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
         <td>Name*:</td>
         <td><input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['name'];?>"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td>Description*:</td>
         <td><input name="des" type="textarea" value="<?php echo $data['description'];?>"  />  
        </td>
        </tr>

        </table>
        <?php }?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <td><img src="<?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];?>"/></td> ?? image path is in DB and you are using $_FILES ?

Comment: @srp003j, its my pleasure :)